# Using the result of a SQL subquery in multiple joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a subquery :-

```
SELECT TOP 1 Months.EndDate
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM FinancialMonth
      WHERE FinancialMonth.EndDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
      AND FinancialMonth.StartDate < GETDATE()
      ORDER BY Period ASC) Months
ORDER BY Months.Period DESC
```

This returns the Month End Date and works for any number of months ago in the last year simply by changing the second `TOP 1`.

My problem is that I need to use this date in a number of `LEFT JOIN` statements where I compare it to two tables.  I also need to return it in the final `SELECT SUM` statement.

By manually inputting the date to the `LEFT JOIN` queries I can run the main query and have a result back in under 1 second.  However if I place this subquery against each `LEFT JOIN` it can take well over a minute to run.  Given that I would like to run this query for each of the last 12 months this is going to tie the server up for an unacceptable amount of time.

Is there any way of running a query and then referencing this result within the `LEFT JOIN` subqueries without it running over and over.  At present it appears to running well over 100k times.

Comment: Check out common table expressions (CTE's)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement would really help.  I can't figure out if you want to return one row for a particular month, 12 rows for different months, or something else.  The structure of the table is also unclear.

Comment: "simply by changing the second TOP 1" it may help if you explain how you change this so we do not have to guess, so "date" is really a set of dates?  We  need more information here.

Comment: Well, I was going to approve the CTE answer that was posted, but looks as though it was deleted now.  Top answer and sorted the problem out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already i dont understand why you use 2 x top 1 (a top 1 in top 1 give 1 row), you query can be simplify to :

```
  SELECT TOP 1 EndDate
  FROM FinancialMonth
  WHERE FinancialMonth.EndDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
  AND FinancialMonth.StartDate < GETDATE()
  ORDER BY Period ASC
```

Now for what you want you can do Something like that:

```
with TblEndDate as (
SELECT TOP 1 EndDate
FROM FinancialMonth
WHERE FinancialMonth.EndDate > DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
AND FinancialMonth.StartDate < GETDATE()
ORDER BY Period ASC
)
select * from othertable f1 
left outer join TblEndDate  f2 on f1.DateInOthertable>=f2.EndDate
```

Comment: The central Top 1 can be changed to any number to get the corresponding number of months from the last year.  The outer Top 1 (sorted in the opposite order) gets the lowest entry from that list.

Comment: i dont understand "the corresponding number of months from the last year". This number can not to be calculate into query?

Comment: If you give an example of data in your table and the result i can help you